# How to combine the output of multiple `find` commands?

Tags: command-line, find

```
find -type f -name "*.avi" -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
```

How to combine these two commands?

1. Either by combining both search terms in one command or
2. So that each command adds its output to the same file.

Hope it's clear what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Combining:

```
find -type f \( -name "*.avi" -or -name '*.mp4' \) -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
```

Adding output to one file:

```
find -type f -name "*.avi" -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec md5sum {} + >> checklist.chk
```

Comment: +1 for also mentioning the possibility of appending to the output file.

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to do this:

Using Or `-o`:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mp4' \) -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
```

Using Regex:

```
find . -type f  -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(avi|mp4)$' -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
```

Both will write the output to the file `checklist.chk`.

Comment: Thanks.. I knew about the -o operator but didn't know the syntax.  Also didn't know about regex can be used like this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

With the `-o` flag ( which is under OPERATORS in `find`'s man page )

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mp4" \) -exec md5sum {} + > checklist.chk
```